# Expression for YYYY-MM-DD~Sucess

Tags: regex, angular, string, typescript

I have written regex for replacing some text

```
x.ServiceLogStatus
    .replace(/Failed/g, "<div class='div1'>\Error</div>")
    .replace(/Match not found/g, "<div class='div1'>\Error</div>"));
```

I also want to add another replacement for the pattern.

```
YYYY-MM-DD 
YYYY-MM-DD~Success
```

How it is possible?

Let say `2001-12-31` i need to replace that date with red color which is inside div.
Let say `2001-12-31~Success`, i need to replace that date with red color which is inside div.

What should i do?

Comment: The `What should i do?` question is considered off-topic by many since the answers can be really any. You can clarify your problem by adding *relevant* code you wrote to solve the current issue. The code you added does not seem relevant to the current issue.

Comment: Well I myself fixed it and answer here below ..

Comment: No idea what you fixed. Glad you worked it out. Anyway, only you could do that since you did not share the code that failed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Myself fixed it

```
x.ServiceLogStatus = x.ServiceLogStatus.replace(/(\d+[-/]\d+[-/]\d+)/g, "<div class='div2'>\ $1</div>").replace(/(\d+[-/]\d+[-/]\d+)/g, "<div class='div4'>\ $1</div>").replace(/~Success/g, "<div class='div2'>\ ~Success</div>"));
```